# Xamarin Android app(not forms). When I run it, its not rotating even though its not fixed to Portrait or Landscape

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, rotation

I'm developing a Xamarin Android app(not forms). When I run it, its not rotating even though its not fixed to Portrait or Landscape. Previously It was running Perfectly but recently I have changed something (which I obviously don't remember) which is effecting the rotation. I have searched online very much but I found only articles and questions discussing Portrait or Landscape. 
(Note: When I open a similar app and rotating it. Its showing landscape perfectly. And then when I choose my App then rotation is working perfectly. Meaning its not rotating on first or unless we choose similar app in Landscape mode)

My Main Activity is something like below

`[Activity(Label = "Thoughts Express", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Icon", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation)]`

And axml is like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
android:id="@+id/LLMain">
<TableLayout
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px".......
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And manifest as below

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:label="Thoughts Express" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></application>
```

Comment: Provide some code

Answer (score 0):

I got it :). Below line was creating problem. Removed it and got solved.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```